# Website Design - Changing only the body content

Tags: asp.net, templates, layout

Currently I am designing a new website and I want to plan it properly.

The main page consists of a Top Content (Header including logo etc) The body with the menu on the left and obviously the footer at the end of the page.

In the menu I have 50 pages and I want to change ONLY the body content of it.

It is not worth it to replicate all the pages (even the ASP.NET code).

For sure there is a better way how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David, what you are looking for is a MasterPage:

http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/masterpages/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are looking because for, you do not mention for example, is the 50 pages almost the same, in other words, only content (letters) change? you can do several things.

I would go, because I do .NET, using [MasterPages](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-09.aspx) in ASP.NET , you design the layout with all the graphics just like it was a template and place a "placeholder" in the "body" part that you mention and you only create 50 pages of content but neither one you write anything relative to the "template"

You can create a Web 2.0 felling and place a DIV that you replace calling the content via AJAX

Maybe you go by other type of language and make use of templates

there are "million" ways to do "everything" :) without more, I can't tell you what could be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use page templates (aka [master pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) in ASP.NET).
Better yet, use a MVC framework. My personal favorite is [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/), but there are others...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend splitting content from form if you haven't already done so.  An example of this is to have your content in one file, and have it reference CSS styles in another file to define how it looks.  That way you can change your content at will and not have to redo all of your style.

One good site that illustrates this is [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/).